# Render element with onClick function inside a loop based on JSON response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

So, I want am having a JSON object which basically contains a list of strings.

I want to iterate over that object and create a div or say an element based on the response as well as a function that would be called onClick.

Right now my code looks as such:

```
response.json

{
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d"
}
```

Render function:

```
var textElement = [];

for(var x in json){
    textElement.push(<h3 onClick=(fetchData(x))>{x}</h3>);
}


return(
    <>
        <h3 onClick=(executeThisFunction())>some other text</h3>
        {textElement}
    </>
);
```

But the problem this causes is that the fetchData function just keeps on being executed until there is an overflow which google automatically pauses.

If I call the fetchData() function via arrow function i.e `onClick =(()=>fetchData(x))` then the function doesn't infinitely call itself, however I need to click it twice in order for the alert to appear.

Also in the return() function, `executeThisFunction()` keeps being executed infinitely.
I am just unable to figure this out.

P.S:
The functions here are simple, but effectively inside them they are going to make a request to the server to fetch new resources/values and work on those.

```
function displayAlert(x){
   dispatch(updateX(x)); //a redux dispatch
   axios.post('https://example.net', {
        'currentText': x
   }).then(doSomething);
}
```

where **doSomething dispatches a function to update the redux store** with current response data.

Edit: Updated the function definitions in the question.
Tried out the changes as suggested, but the `some other text` element still causes Maximum call stack size exceeded automatically.

Comment: `onClick` takes a function. You are passing it the _result_ of calling one of your functions, which is some value, probably `undefined`. This is the difference between `executeThisFunction` and `executeThisFunction()`. Passing the latter causes your function to run on every render, which itself triggers re-renders and leads to the 'overflow' you describe.

Answer (score 0):

`onClick={someFn}` or `onClick={(x)=>someFn(x,y)}` these are the right ways to call a function. Further, you need to loop over `textElement` array using map and then set an `onClick` listener to each index of `textElement`

Comment: Could you provide an example on the loop over text element using map?

Comment: {textElement.map((text)=>(
      <h3 onClick={()=>someFn()}>text</h3>
))}

Comment: I think this would be redundant, since I am actually constructing the element from the json response. So I guess I can directly map that instead.